# Error: Type 'SelectNotificationCallback' not found. SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Can somebody Help me to fixed this code? it shows

**Error: Type 'SelectNotificationCallback' not found.     SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,**

please help me guys i need your help this time

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications_linux/flutter_local_notifications_linux.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart';

import 'initialization_settings.dart';
import 'notification_details.dart';
import 'platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'platform_specifics/ios/enums.dart';
import 'types.dart';

/// Provides cross-platform functionality for displaying local notifications.
///
/// The plugin will check the platform that is running on to use the appropriate
/// platform-specific implementation of the plugin. The plugin methods will be a
/// no-op when the platform can't be detected.
///
/// Use [resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation] and pass the platform-specific
/// type of the plugin to get the underlying platform-specific implementation
/// if access to platform-specific APIs are needed.
class FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin {
  /// Factory for create an instance of [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin].
  factory FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin() => _instance;

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin._() {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance =
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance =
          IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance =
          MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux) {
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance =
          LinuxFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    }
  }

  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _instance =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin._();

  /// Returns the underlying platform-specific implementation of given type [T],
  /// which must be a concrete subclass of [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/latest/flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform-class.html)
  ///
  /// Requires running on the appropriate platform that matches the specified
  /// type for a result to be returned. For example, when the specified type
  /// argument is of type [AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin], this will
  /// only return a result of that type when running on Android.
  T? resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      T extends FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform>() {
    if (T == FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform) {
      throw ArgumentError.value(
          T,
          'The type argument must be a concrete subclass of '
          'FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform');
    }
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return null;
    }

    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android &&
        T == AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin &&
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance
            is AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) {
      return FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance as T?;
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS &&
        T == IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin &&
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance
            is IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) {
      return FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance as T?;
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS &&
        T == MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin &&
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance
            is MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) {
      return FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance as T?;
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux &&
        T == LinuxFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin &&
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance
            is LinuxFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) {
      return FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance as T?;
    }

    return null;
  }

  /// Initializes the plugin.
  ///
  /// Call this method on application before using the plugin further.
  ///
  /// Will return a [bool] value to indicate if initialization succeeded.
  /// On iOS this is dependent on if permissions have been granted to show
  /// notification When running in environment that is neither Android and
  /// iOS (e.g. when running tests), this will be a no-op and return true.
  ///
  /// Note that on iOS, initialisation may also request notification
  /// permissions where users will see a permissions prompt. This may be fine
  /// in cases where it's acceptable to do this when the application runs for
  /// the first time. However, if your application needs to do this at a later
  /// point in time, set the [IOSInitializationSettings.requestAlertPermission],
  /// [IOSInitializationSettings.requestBadgePermission] and
  /// [IOSInitializationSettings.requestSoundPermission] values to false.
  /// [IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.requestPermissions] can then be called
  /// to request permissions when needed.
  ///
  /// To handle when a notification launched an application, use
  /// [getNotificationAppLaunchDetails].
  Future<bool?> initialize(
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings, {
    SelectNotificationCallback? onSelectNotification,
  }) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return true;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.initialize(initializationSettings.android!,
              onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.initialize(initializationSettings.iOS!,
              onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      return await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.initialize(initializationSettings.macOS!,
              onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux) {
      return await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              LinuxFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.initialize(initializationSettings.linux!,
              onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    }
    return true;
  }

  /// Returns info on if a notification created from this plugin had been used
  /// to launch the application.
  ///
  /// An example of how this could be used is to change the initial route of
  /// your application when it starts up. If the plugin isn't running on either
  /// Android, iOS or macOS then an instance of the
  /// `NotificationAppLaunchDetails` class is returned with
  /// `didNotificationLaunchApp` set to false.
  ///
  /// Note that this will return null for applications running on macOS
  /// versions older than 10.14. This is because there's currently no mechanism
  /// for plugins to receive information on lifecycle events.
  Future<NotificationAppLaunchDetails?>
      getNotificationAppLaunchDetails() async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return null;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      return await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    } else {
      return await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance
              .getNotificationAppLaunchDetails() ??
          const NotificationAppLaunchDetails(false, null);
    }
  }

  /// Show a notification with an optional payload that will be passed back to
  /// the app when a notification is tapped.
  Future<void> show(
    int id,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    NotificationDetails? notificationDetails, {
    String? payload,
  }) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.show(id, title, body,
              notificationDetails: notificationDetails?.android,
              payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.show(id, title, body,
              notificationDetails: notificationDetails?.iOS, payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.show(id, title, body,
              notificationDetails: notificationDetails?.macOS,
              payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.linux) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              LinuxFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.show(id, title, body,
              notificationDetails: notificationDetails?.linux,
              payload: payload);
    } else {
      await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance.show(id, title, body);
    }
  }

  /// Cancel/remove the notification with the specified id.
  ///
  /// This applies to notifications that have been scheduled and those that
  /// have already been presented.
  ///
  /// The `tag` parameter specifies the Android tag. If it is provided,
  /// then the notification that matches both the id and the tag will
  /// be canceled. `tag` has no effect on other platforms.
  Future<void> cancel(int id, {String? tag}) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.cancel(id, tag: tag);
    } else {
      await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance.cancel(id);
    }
  }

  /// Cancels/removes all notifications.
  ///
  /// This applies to notifications that have been scheduled and those that
  /// have already been presented.
  Future<void> cancelAll() async {
    await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance.cancelAll();
  }

  /// Schedules a notification to be shown at the specified date and time.
  ///
  /// The [androidAllowWhileIdle] parameter determines if the notification
  /// should still be shown at the exact time even when the device is in a
  /// low-power idle mode.
  @Deprecated('Deprecated due to problems with time zones. Use zonedSchedule '
      'instead.')
  Future<void> schedule(
    int id,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    DateTime scheduledDate,
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails, {
    String? payload,
    bool androidAllowWhileIdle = false,
  }) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
          .schedule(id, title, body, scheduledDate, notificationDetails.android,
              payload: payload, androidAllowWhileIdle: androidAllowWhileIdle);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.schedule(id, title, body, scheduledDate, notificationDetails.iOS,
              payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }

  /// Schedules a notification to be shown at the specified date and time
  /// relative to a specific time zone.
  ///
  /// Note that to get the appropriate representation of the time at the native
  /// level (i.e. Android/iOS), the plugin needs to pass the time over the
  /// platform channel in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. Therefore, the precision
  /// is at the best to the second.
  ///
  /// The [androidAllowWhileIdle] parameter determines if the notification
  /// should still be shown at the exact time even when the device is in a
  /// low-power idle mode.
  ///
  /// The [uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation] is for iOS versions older
  /// than 10 as the APIs have limited support for time zones. With this
  /// parameter, it is used to determine if the scheduled date should be
  /// interpreted as absolute time or wall clock time.
  ///
  /// If a value for [matchDateTimeComponents] parameter is given, this tells
  /// the plugin to schedule a recurring notification that matches the
  /// specified date and time components. Specifying
  /// [DateTimeComponents.time] would result in a daily notification at the
  /// same time whilst [DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime] would result
  /// in a weekly notification that occurs on the same day of the week and time.
  /// This is similar to how recurring notifications on iOS/macOS work using a
  /// calendar trigger. Note that when a value is given, the [scheduledDate]
  /// may not represent the first time the notification will be shown. An
  /// example would be if the date and time is currently 2020-10-19 11:00
  /// (i.e. 19th October 2020 11:00AM) and [scheduledDate] is 2020-10-21
  /// 10:00 and the value of the [matchDateTimeComponents] is
  /// [DateTimeComponents.time], then the next time a notification will
  /// appear is 2020-10-20 10:00.
  Future<void> zonedSchedule(
    int id,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    TZDateTime scheduledDate,
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails, {
    required UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation,
    required bool androidAllowWhileIdle,
    String? payload,
    DateTimeComponents? matchDateTimeComponents,
  }) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
          .zonedSchedule(
              id, title, body, scheduledDate, notificationDetails.android,
              payload: payload,
              androidAllowWhileIdle: androidAllowWhileIdle,
              matchDateTimeComponents: matchDateTimeComponents);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.zonedSchedule(
              id, title, body, scheduledDate, notificationDetails.iOS,
              uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
                  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation,
              payload: payload,
              matchDateTimeComponents: matchDateTimeComponents);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.zonedSchedule(
              id, title, body, scheduledDate, notificationDetails.macOS,
              payload: payload,
              matchDateTimeComponents: matchDateTimeComponents);
    }
  }

  /// Periodically show a notification using the specified interval.
  ///
  /// For example, specifying a hourly interval means the first time the
  /// notification will be an hour after the method has been called and
  /// then every hour after that.
  ///
  /// If [androidAllowWhileIdle] is `false`, the Android `AlarmManager` APIs
  /// are used to set a recurring inexact alarm that would present the
  /// notification. This means that there may be delay in on when
  /// notifications are displayed. If [androidAllowWhileIdle] is `true`, the
  /// Android `AlarmManager` APIs are used to schedule a single notification
  /// to be shown at the exact time even when the device is in a low-power idle
  /// mode. After it is shown, the next one would be scheduled and this would
  /// repeat.
  Future<void> periodicallyShow(
    int id,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    RepeatInterval repeatInterval,
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails, {
    String? payload,
    bool androidAllowWhileIdle = false,
  }) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.periodicallyShow(id, title, body, repeatInterval,
              notificationDetails: notificationDetails.android,
              payload: payload,
              androidAllowWhileIdle: androidAllowWhileIdle);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.periodicallyShow(id, title, body, repeatInterval,
              notificationDetails: notificationDetails.iOS, payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.periodicallyShow(id, title, body, repeatInterval,
              notificationDetails: notificationDetails.macOS, payload: payload);
    } else {
      await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance
          .periodicallyShow(id, title, body, repeatInterval);
    }
  }

  /// Shows a notification on a daily interval at the specified time.
  @Deprecated(
      'Deprecated due to problems with time zones. Use zonedSchedule instead '
      'by passing a date in the future with the same time and pass '
      'DateTimeComponents.matchTime as the value of the '
      'matchDateTimeComponents parameter.')
  Future<void> showDailyAtTime(
    int id,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    Time notificationTime,
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails, {
    String? payload,
  }) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.showDailyAtTime(
              id, title, body, notificationTime, notificationDetails.android,
              payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.showDailyAtTime(
              id, title, body, notificationTime, notificationDetails.iOS,
              payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }

  /// Shows a notification on weekly interval at the specified day and time.
  @Deprecated(
      'Deprecated due to problems with time zones. Use zonedSchedule instead '
      'by passing a date in the future with the same day of the week and time '
      'as well as passing DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime as the value of '
      'the matchDateTimeComponents parameter.')
  Future<void> showWeeklyAtDayAndTime(
    int id,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    Day day,
    Time notificationTime,
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails, {
    String? payload,
  }) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return;
    }
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.showWeeklyAtDayAndTime(id, title, body, day, notificationTime,
              notificationDetails.android,
              payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      await resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.showWeeklyAtDayAndTime(
              id, title, body, day, notificationTime, notificationDetails.iOS,
              payload: payload);
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }

  /// Returns a list of notifications pending to be delivered/shown.
  Future<List<PendingNotificationRequest>> pendingNotificationRequests() =>
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance.pendingNotificationRequests();

  /// Returns a list of notifications that are already delivered/shown.
  Future<List<ActiveNotification>> getActiveNotifications() =>
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlatform.instance.getActiveNotifications();
}
```

i tried to change but if someone could fix it where to replcae those much appreciated i bought this code year ago now i ecnountered error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: dont just post the full project, try to make it minimal

Comment: When requesting help, try to post code that results in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Try to trim your code down to just the bits where the exception is occurring (you can get the method and line number from your stack trace).  Then provide further description of what is supposed to happen vs what is actually happening.  What are your expectations?  Just posting a large block of code and saying "fix-this" won't get much help.